# Is it just me or did a lot of people's rep just go way up?

Tags: support, reputation

I've been monitoring some of the higher reps we have on the site to see how we were doing on the area 51 stats and it seems like a bunch of people just blasted way up.  Pretty sure when I looked last week the highest ones were around 2k, I just looked now and the highest are around 8k.

Am I imagining things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old SharePoint Overflow content was just migrated into the site. Everyone's reputation from back then was imported alongside it, with gains for some reaching 6000, perhaps even higher.

I... just got 2 reputation, myself.

Comment: `I... just got 2 reputation, myself.` Let the good times roll!

Comment: I got a 6k boost, which is all of my old rep. Woo! :)

Comment: I'm going to have to learn a lot more about SP to get on that first page now... Nothing like a challenge to get you moving. :)

Comment: @James, congrats!  I remember you got slammed back to zero right after the move.

Comment: :D Took me a while. Also, @Stuart, you get rep on upvoted questions too, so ask some, even if it's to get a different perspective on something you might already know the answer to.

Comment: Good to see you got your well-earned rep. back Jim! On the other hand, I was closing in on you just before you got boosted - damn ;-)

Comment: And another consequence is that answerred questions is down to 71% so we should probably do a spring clean...

Comment: Good news really, appreciated!

Comment: Nice, now we need to work through the unanswered ones!